# How to use Powershell global variable inside CMD.EXE statement

Tags: windows, variables, powershell, cmd, global-variables

I'm trying to automate printer installation using powershell with imbedded CMD.exe code. To optimize the code and reduce the amount of typing, I use global variables, which works fine with powershell code. However, as soon as it hits the embedded CMD.exe code with its single and double quotation marks, the global variables are not recognized anymore. I tried using single or double quotation marks, but still no luck.
The problematic parameter is at Line #21, switch /r .
Any ideas on how to fix it?

> **Note:** This code is for Powershell_v2.

```
$h = get-content env:computername 
$global:portIP1 = "printer01"
$global:portIP2 = "printer02"


  if ($h -match 'nhi') {$global:portIP1 
$portNumber = "9100"  
$computer = $env:COMPUTERNAME 

$wmi= [wmiclass]"\\$computer\root\cimv2:win32_tcpipPrinterPort" 
#$wmi.psbase.scope.options.enablePrivileges = $true 
$newPort = $wmi.createInstance() 

$newPort.hostAddress = $global:portIP1 
$newPort.name = $global:portIP1 
$newPort.portNumber = $portNumber 
$newPort.SNMPEnabled = $True 
$newPort.Protocol = 1 
$newPort.put()

CMD /C 'printui.exe /if /b "PrinterB&W1" /f "C:\inetpub\ftproot\Prdrivers\HP Universal Print Driver\hpcu155u.inf_amd64_neutral_bcdaf832a18b6add/hpcu155u.inf" /r '$global:portIP1' /m "HP Universal Printing PCL 6"'
CMD /C 'printui.exe/y /n"PrinterB&W1', (Write-Host "match found")}
```

Comment: What about those last two lines requires you use `cmd.exe` at all? PowerShell can execute EXEs just fine without it.

Comment: @alroc True. I've updated the question's code.

Comment: Question update: Note added to the question.

Comment: You still didn't answer the question I asked.

Comment: @alroc I thought you were asking about the .exe extension...my bad, I didn't get your question correctly. Yes those last 2 lined must use CMD.exe, because Powershell v2 doesn't include printer install cmdlet, it only comes in Powershell v3.

Comment: No, my point is that Powershell can call EXEs directly, you don't have to jump out to another environment (`cmd.exe`) to run them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use an expandable (double-quoted) here-string.  Then you can put whatever kind of quotes you want, whereever you want them and they'll get parsed as literal text:

```
  $global:portIP1 = "printer01"
  $global:portIP2 = "printer02"

$command = @"
'printui.exe /if /b "PrinterB&W1" /f "C:\inetpub\ftproot\Prdrivers\HP Universal Print Driver\hpcu155u.inf_amd64_neutral_bcdaf832a18b6add/hpcu155u.inf" /r '$global:portIP1' /m "HP Universal Printing PCL 6"'
"@
CMD /C $command
```

The opening @" can be in any position, but the closing "@ must start in position 1 on the line.

See `Get-Help about_quoting_rules` for more information about here-strings.

Comment: alternatively the command could have been re-written with escape characters on the offending single/double quotes so that Powershell parses the line correctly and passes off to cmd.exe without error.